# Extend third-party interface

Tags: angular, typescript

In [tutorial](https://leanpub.com/essentialtypescript/read#leanpub-auto-extending-interface-definitions) I read how to extend interfaces. Say I have a third-party library with some interface. Tutorial states that I can simply define another interface with exact same name and it will extend the previous:

```
// third-party source
interface jQueryElement {
    data(name: string): any;
    data(name: string, data: any): jQueryElement;
}

// my code
interface jQueryElement {
    todo(): Todo;
    todo(todo: Todo): void;
}
```

Ok, but how you import them? Name collision would't happen?

Sorry, I haven't coded anything in Typescript alone, only in Angular, so I wonder can I follow that approach or the only way is to define other interface with `extends`?:

```
interface jQueryElement2 extends jQueryElement {
    todo(): Todo;
    todo(todo: Todo): void;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend interfaces that way when they are in the same scope. `JQuery` declaration files declare interfaces in the global scope, so that's not a problem.

You simply add a `jquery-extension.d.ts` file to your project (the name is not important), and then declare the interface again, adding the methds or properties you want. Then, TypeScript will pick it up and will mix the two type declarations in one.

Of course, declaring the methods only will make TypeScript think they exist. You still have to actually define them (in another file, not the `d.ts`file), or you'll get a runtime error when trying to execute them.

An example: `jquery-extension.d.ts`

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    count(): number;
}
```

`jquery-extension.ts`:

```
jQuery.fn.count = function() {
    return this.length;
}
```

If you just add the above code without extending the interface, TypeScript will protest, saying that `count` is not a known property of the `JQueryStatic` interface.
Then you just make sure to import `jquery-extension.ts` in the entry point of your application:

```
import 'jquery-extension'
```

And done. The `d.ts` file does not need to be imported, as they are ambient declaration files and the compiler picks them up by itself.

Comment: Ah, ok. Wasn't aware of that they are in the global scope... Thanks, great explanation!

Comment: In this case, yes. In other cases, if the interface is defined inside a module or a namespace, you must declare the module/namespace, too, and extend the interface inside, because differente namespaces/modules can export interfaces/classes with the same names without conflict.